# ADFS with SAML2.0 WebSSO Protocol. SignatureVerificationFailed

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier ( IsReadOnly = False, Count = 1, Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause ) '

When connect from sp to idp seeing this error on EventViewer on ADFS settings.

what is do I need to send. or do I need a specific claim rule defined.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide us with code for how you're assembling your claim, and triggering the authentication request?

Comment: I m using component pro trial version to implement client side saml stack example ComponentPro\UltimateSaml-Pro v7.0.226.132\Samples\Saml\Web\CS\Saml2-AdvancedApi\Saml2IdPInitiated. I m confused on which certificate I need in this ServiceProvider_2013 project from ADFS. is tokendescripting certificate or tokan signing certificate. not sure what is key.pfx and EncryptionKey.pfx file in both project within the solution.